# "accessRules()" in YII

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I use YII framework and limiting access to some pages with accessRules and filter. There are much information of how to limit access without DB or how to do it with always getting access variable, but how can I do it only getting the role from the database and with access filters in my controller.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}


public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update', 'view', 'index'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete', 'view', 'index'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already set up a role based hierachy? If not check this yii docu: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth  If so, it is as simple as that:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update', 'view', 'index'),
            'roles'=>array('role1'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete', 'view', 'index'),
            'roles'=>array('role2'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Oooooh, so simple solution. Thank you

Comment: if the answer of @user619 is the correct one, you should accept it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

comment line which says `'postOnly + delete'` in

```
 `public function filters()
  {
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        //'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
  }
```

`This will allow deletion for users.